# how to use split and strip in python for lines with multiple delimiters on linux

Tags: python, linux, delimiter

I have a list like

```
a= [(0.11004363790442408, '0 22'),
    (1.0003303788789184, '1 7'),
    (0.9427256865065468, '15 23'),
    (0.3508626679066326, '8 21'),
    (1.0815767762687958, '5 27'),
    (0.2889125295483047, '19 26'),
    (0.9294135566237669, '4 10')]
```

I want to access single entities like follows as sample for the first bracket. Here only 7 entries are shown; in real case these are in millions!

```
ID[0]= 0.11004363790442408
ID[1]=0
ID[2]=22
```

I wrote something like

```
entities=len(a)
for data in range(entities):
 lineContent=a.strip(' ').split(' ').split(',')
 print lineContent
 ID[0]= lineContent [0]
 ID[1]= lineContent [1]
 ID[2]= lineContent [2]
```

There should be some loop for all the entries, so I used a `for` loop over the range. Any suggestions?

Please also elaborate the splitting so that it could be modified.

Comment: What _exactly_ have you tried so far? `a.strip(' ')` won't work, since `a` seems to be a list in your case

Comment: switch the function calls

Comment: Don't  invent some over-the-top elaborate ways. Just loop over the list and `split(' ')` the 2nd element of each tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
entities = len(a)

for data in range(entities):
    ID = []
    ID.append(a[data][0])
    ID.extend(a[data][1].split(' '))
    print("ID[0] = {0}\nID[1] = {1}\nID[2] = {2}\n".format(ID[0], ID[1], ID[2]))
```

don't know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple task and there are numerous ways to solve it. Here's one:

```
a= [(0.11004363790442408, '0 22'),
    (1.0003303788789184, '1 7'),
    (0.9427256865065468, '15 23'),
    (0.3508626679066326, '8 21'),
    (1.0815767762687958, '5 27'),
    (0.2889125295483047, '19 26'),
    (0.9294135566237669, '4 10')]


# no iterator, just the list elements
for lst in a:
    # make a new list containing only the float at first
    ID = [lst[0]]
    # extend the list with the two tuple values cast to int 
    ID.extend(int(x) for x in lst[1].split(" "))
    print ID
```

And another (basically the same thing but shorter):

```
for lst in a:
    ID = [lst[0]] + [int(x) for x in lst[1].split(" ")]
```